# Vaadin Invient Chart Addon not loading

Tags: charts, vaadin

I like the way how Invient Charts Addon in Vaadin works and I configured everything as described. But I have a problem. A weird one! When I load the chart, labels and tooltips are visible but not the chart series. But when I open firebug and close it, Chart loads fine. Also  if I jus press 'alt button', chart loads fine. If I refresh again its gone. Any Idea anybody? Please help me

**SOLVED** Was previously using 'page.append' to import js files. Using 'page.write' solved the issue.

Comment: You could answer your own question and mark it as accepted answer. It makes it easier for people to find non-answered/answered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was previously using 'page.append' to import js files. Using 'page.write' solved the issue